# Doing scopes & closures in JS

Tags: javascript, closures

I wrote a code for scope and closure

```
function fun1(){
    let a = 2
    function fun2(){
        console.log(a)
    }
    return fun2
}

b = fun1()
console.log(b)
```

According to me, I am storing fun1 function inside of b variable. fun1() is returning me fun2 method which should do console.log(a) i.e. value 2....

But here it's only giving me [Function: fun2]

What am I missing or not doing ?

Comment: _"I am storing fun1 function inside of b variable"_ No, you're storing the return value `fun2` in `b`. You have to learn the difference between a function (name of the function without parentheses) and a function call (name of the function with parentheses).

Answer (score -2):

Since you return fun2() from fun1() and you call fun1() in `b`'s declaration, `b` is fun2 after the declartion so you should call it to get `a` logged.
Also note the fun2() returns undefined. So probably logging b()'s output is redundant:

```js
function fun1(){
    let a = 2
    function fun2(){
        console.log(a)
    }
    return fun2
}

const b = fun1()
console.log(b())
```

Comment: isn't just the lack of parentheses the problem here?